# Multiplicative inverses and co-primes

Tags: modular-arithmetic, multiplicative-function

I'm working out some examples on multiplicative inverses. I understand how to solve for a multiplicative inverse using the Extended Euler's algorithm, but I don't understand the principles which enable this solution.

In particular, everything notes that for a multiplicative inverse to exist of a number a in multiplicative group modulo n, that a and n must be co-prime (thus, GCD(a,n) = 1).

I can work out plenty of examples where I won't be able to find a multiplicative inverse if they are not co-prime -- but I don't understand *why* this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ak\equiv 1 \pmod n\,$ means, for some $\,j,\,$ $\,ak+nj = 1,\,$ so $\,d\mid a,n\,\Rightarrow\, d\mid 1,\,$ so $\,\gcd(a,n)=1.$

Conversely, by the ext Euclidean algorithm $\, \gcd(a,n)=1\,\Rightarrow\, ak+nj = 1\,\Rightarrow\,ak\equiv 1\pmod n,\, $ for some $\,j,k.$

Comment: I can follow everything in your first statement, until you make the claim that because `d|a,n` and `d|1` that the `gcd(a,n) = 1`. I see that if `d|1`, then d must be 1. But I don't understand how you can jump to knowing the GCD of the two things must be `1` from this. (I'm guessing it is because there is no other combination of `k,j` for which this equation will equal 1, and for which `d` will divide `a,n` and also divide `ak + nk` (1).

Comment: @BSchlinker The proof shows that the only (positive) common divisor of $\,a,n\,$ is $\,d = 1.\,$ Therefore, in particular, their *greatest* common divisor is $\, 1.\ \ $

Comment: @BSchlinker More generally, using essentially the same method, one can show $\ ax\equiv b\pmod n\ $ has a solution $\,x\iff \gcd(a,n)\mid b.\,$ Yours is the special case $\,b = 1.\ \ $

Comment: @BSchlinker One can also view it is terms of *divisibility* mod $\,n,\,$ namely, notice that $\ ax\equiv b\pmod n\,$ is solvable $\iff a\mid b\pmod n\iff (a,n)\mid b,\,$ see [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/158719/242)