# Prove $\overline{a} \mid \overline{b} \iff gcd(a,n) \mid gcd(b,n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

Let $\overline{a},\overline{b} \in\mathbb{Z}_n$. If $\overline{a}\mid\overline{b}$, then $gcd(a,n) \mid gcd(b,n).$

**Proof:**

$(\Rightarrow)$ By definition, $\overline{a},\overline{b} \in\mathbb{Z}_n \Leftrightarrow a \equiv 0 \pmod n, b \equiv 0 \pmod n.$ Subtracting those, we get $a-b \equiv 0 \pmod n$, i.e., $a-b=nq \Leftrightarrow b=a-nq \,(1), \,q\in\mathbb{Z}.$

By definition, $gcd(a,n) \mid a$ and $gcd(a,n) \mid n \,(2)$. Then, by $(1)$ and $(2)$, $gcd(a,n) \mid b$.

Also by definition, $gcd(a,n)=ax+ny$ and $gcd(b,n)=bv+nw.$ We know $gcd(a,n) \mid n$ and $gcd(a,n) \mid b$. Therefore, $gcd(a,n) \mid gcd(b,n).$

$(\Leftarrow)$ I'm still thinking about it.

Is this proof correct?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes this is correct so far.

Comment: By [here in dupe](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/158719/242) $\, a\mid b\,$ in $\Bbb Z_n\!\!\iff (a,n)\mid b\!\!\overset{\rm \color{#c00}U\!\!}\iff (a,n)\mid (b,n)\,$ where $\rm\color{#c00}U$ = [gcd universal propergty](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/198801/242)

Comment: The first sentence of the argument is already incorrect,. $\bar a \in \Bbb Z_n\,$ denotes a  coset $\,a+n\Bbb Z,\,$ which is the set of all integers $\equiv a\pmod{n},\,$ but this is not equivalent to $\,a\equiv 0\pmod{n}\,$ as you claim.

Comment: The linked answer in the dupe (just now clarified) proves this relation between divisibility in $\Bbb Z$ and divisibility in $\Bbb Z_n = \Bbb Z\bmod n\ \ $